# Using DOMContentLoaded and window.onload in selenium java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, domcontentloaded

Is there a way I could use javascript's document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready)
and window.onload() in selenium script in java ?

Something like :
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)Driver;
js.executeScript("return document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready)");
or
js.executeScript("return window.onload()");

Comment: DOMContentLoaded is also fired before the entire page has been loaded. DCL fires immediately the page has been parsed, i.e. the ending body tag has been found. At this stage you've all the tags in the document of the page, i.e. the DOM has been created for this page, but all the content is not necessarily loaded yet.  Window.onload fires after all the resources (e.g. images and iframes etc) on the page has been __fully__ loaded.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for the detailed explanation.